# How to use AspNet.Identity in Azure Mobile App

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, azure, mobile

Using the new [Azure Mobile App](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/mobile/) in combination with a MVC5 Web App hosted as [Azure Web App](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/web/). Both Applications are using the same EntityFramework database.

The models are shared between the projects and all models inherit from [EntityData class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/microsoft.windowsazure.mobile.service.entitydata.aspx) so that the mobile app have all needed columns (string id, version etc).

Now I would like to implement AspNet.Identity to manage users.
Every entity has now an ApplicationUser property, so that I can filter for entity belonging to the current Identity user.

Since the ApplicationUser class inherits IdentityUser class I cannot inherit from EntityData class anymore.

So, how can I get IdentityUser work with mobile apps?

Comment: Don't suppose you ever got to the bottom of this as I am having the same issue?